# Concatenate strings within a Spring XML configuration file?

Tags: java, xml, spring, configuration

I have a String value in a Spring configuration file that comes to be as the result of a JNDI lookup -- it happens to be a path name:

`<jee:jndi-lookup id="myAppHomeDir" jndi-name="myAppHomeDir" />`

Now I need to concatenate on to the end of this path another string and hand it off to another Spring bean as follows (which of course doesn't work):

```
<bean id="LogPath" class="org.mystuff.initBean">
    <property name="logDirectory">
       <jee:jndi-lookup id="myAppHomeDir"
                 jndi-name="myAppHomeDir" /> + "/logs"
    </property>
</bean>
```

Is there a simple way to do this without me having to write a utility class in Java?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Try using [Spring EL (expression language)](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html). I would try the following (not tested):

```
<jee:jndi-lookup id="myAppHomeDir" jndi-name="myAppHomeDir" />

<bean id="LogPath" class="org.mystuff.initBean">
    <property name="logDirectory" value="#{myAppHomeDir+'/logs'}"/>
</bean>
```

Not quite sure if it would work. The thing that troubles me is the cast from File (I guess) to String when concatenating. So if the previous one didn't work, I would try:

```
#{myAppHomeDir.canonicalPath+'/logs'}
```

Let us know if it works.

Comment: Worked perfectly.  I've been using Spring forever, but really never exercised the Spring expression language.  Going to have to brush up on that....thanks.