# Spring XML conf - join two params from jdbc.properties

Tags: java, database, spring, jdbc

I want to divide JDBC URL and URL params.

In jdbc.properties I have:

```
jdbc.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://db.server.tld:3306/dbName
jdbc.username=user
jdbc.password=pass
jdbc.urlParams=?useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=utf-8
```

In spring xml config:

```
<bean id="propertyConfigurer"
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="location"><value>classpath:jdbc.properties</value></property>
</bean>
<bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}" />
    <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}${jdbc.urlParams}" />
    <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />
</bean>
```

But it  doesn't work.
Is there any way to join these two params?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Concatenate strings within a Spring XML configuration file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261372/concatenate-strings-within-a-spring-xml-configuration-file)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have included [Spring Expression Language](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html) (section 8.4) module with your application, you should be able to use the following:

```
#{'${jdbc.url}' + '${jdbc.urlParams}'}
```

as the value for `url` property.

Comment: If I use "#{'${jdbc.url}' + '${jdbc.urlParams}'}" encoding is bad.

<property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}?useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=utf-8" /> works, but I can't edit params from jdbc.properties :-(

Comment: try <property name="url" value="#{jdbc.url + jdbc.urlParams}" />

Comment: http://pastebin.com/hFAFBPwX Expression parsing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E:(pos 0): Field or property 'jdbc' cannot be found on object of type 'org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanExpressionContext'